# I built my Unity on HTML5 WebGL and this error message shows up when I try to launch it

Tags: html, unity-game-engine

[image]

> Unable to parse Build/Pain.framework.js.br! Loading pre-compressed (brotli or gzip) content via a file:// URL without a web server is not supported by this browser. Please use a local development web server to host compressed Unity content, or use the Unity Build and Run option.
> Monopoly A3

Comment: Message is pretty self-explanatory. You can't run the content directly from disk, you have to host it through, at minimum, a local web server.

Comment: Ah, how do I do that?
I'm very sorry if it's a dumb question haha, I'm just a script kiddie

Comment: It's a better question than the first =).  Depends on your OS, but I assume you're on windows.  Have a google for WampServer and grab it from SourceForge.

Comment: I'm back and I've hosted it on GitHub and tried it out, didn't work and another error message came up. I'll try WampServer now. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The message is pretty self-explanatory: you'll need a local server to do that. They're countless ways to do that but here's one of them:

### [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Just download it and run it (The XAMPP Control Panel - Apache -> Start). Then put your files in `C:\xampp\htdocs\` (On Windows, not sure for other systems).
`C:\xampp\htdocs\` Will be the equivalent of `http://localhost` in your browser, so if you put `example.txt` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\`, it will be available at `http://localhost/example.txt`.

### Other options

XAMPP is my personal favorite, but they're other options, like the other `*AMP`, like [WAMP](https://www.wampserver.com/), [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en) and [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)), for Windows, MacOS, and Linux respectively (XAMPP being multiplatform - Also [more exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache%E2%80%93MySQL%E2%80%93PHP_packages) is you're curious).

They're also "simpler" solution (in the sense of more lightweight ones) like [http-server](https://npmjs.com/package/http-server) for NodeJS, or Python's [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). But they need to be executed on the right folder each time. Both solutions works fine so it's up to you to choose your preferred.